# How to use between in case clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have like following table.

```
type  score
A     1
A    10
A    90
A   100  
A   101
B     1
B    10
B   101
B   200
B   201
C     1
C    10
C   101
C   200
C   201
　・
　・
```

I'd like to extract score by range. if type in `A` then `1~100` and if type other than `A` then `100~200`

```
type score
A    1
A   10 
A   90
A  100
B  101
B  200
C  101
C  200
　・
　・
```

I tried like following query, but it didn't workwell.

```
select *
from table
where case when type in ('A') then between 1 and 100 else 100 and 200
```

I'd like to avoid `union` clause because it execute sequential scan manytimes and the code becomes long

If someone has opinion or materials please let me know
Thanks

Comment: use `or`, `(type = 'A' and score between 1 and 100) or (type = 'B' and score between 100 and 200)`

Comment: Or UNION ALL 2 separate queries - by 'A' and by not 'A'. Or `WHERE score BETWEEN CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 100 END AND CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN 100 ELSE 200 END` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing `score` for your `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
 FROM mytable
 WHERE CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('A') THEN score BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
                           ELSE score BETWEEN 100 AND 200 END;
```

If you have other condition, you can always add another `WHEN` like the following:

```
SELECT *
 FROM mytable
 WHERE CASE WHEN type IN ('A') THEN score BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
            WHEN type IN ('B','C') THEN score BETWEEN 100 AND 200 ELSE 0 END
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d29d72ad4054805ec7c1cbf431c6ffa)

Comment: `ELSE 0` is doubtful... `ELSE score BETWEEN 100 AND 200` seems to be more logical, OP needs in *if type other than A then*.